# Can I write elisp code to act on the text in a buffer

Tags: spacemacs, text-editing

I am fairly new to emacs and I want to learn emacs Lisp. In particular, is it possible to write elisp functions in, say, the *scratch* buffer to do some complex text-processing on my program file `example.cpp` whose buffer I would have open in another frame.

Indeed if I could write some elisp code to do text-processing across all the files in the project folder that would be even better!

I am using Spacemacs

Comment: Elisp is perfect for performing text operations on the content of a buffers, you can define your functions in `*scratch*' or, even better, in a separate file. However, there is no concept of "project" in Emacs (even though some packages provides project-like support).

Comment: @lawlist I do agree with your comment.  But, I was also in the same situation as him until I discovered `with-current-buffer`.  Once you know how to act on a desired buffer, you feel you passed the hardest cliff of leaning elisp and see the huge possibilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can! (If you mean frame what Emacs think it is.)

To demonstrate, do the following steps:

## Run Emacs

This will put you into the `*scratch*` buffer.

## Create a new frame

`M-x make-frame-command` to create a new frame, which is also in `*scratch*`.

## Open `example.cpp`

So that you can now see both `*scratch*` buffer in the first frame and `example.cpp` in the newly created frame, side by side.

## Write lisp

Copy the following code and past it into the `*scratch*` buffer.

```
(with-current-buffer "example.cpp"
  (insert "Hello, Emacs!\n"))
```

## Evaluate it

Put your cursor after the last `)` and do `M-x eval-last-sexp`.  If you see "Hello, Emacs!" in the other frame, you got the first step right.  You can now customize the code to suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I also needed to turn the scratch buffer into "Emacs-Lisp" mode. I am using Spacmacs. While in scratch buffer press SPC SPC emacs-lisp-mode <RTN>.